# How can I fire a method programmatically, that's described by an selector?

Tags: objective-c

Example: I have a selector like this, which I give to another method as parameter:

```
SEL mySelector = @selector(doSomething:);
```

I would like to call that doSomething method now inside that method.

Background: I have an method that performs some core animation actions. It uses already the didStopSelector, which calls an special memory management method when everything is done. But then, I want to be able to call a simple method that takes no special parameters, to do some stuff afterwards. But that method shall not be responsible for calling the memory management method, so I need to fire an selector that I store in an ivar, for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[receivingObject performSelector:mySelector withObject:someParam];
```

There's a version without `withObject` if your selector doesn't take any parameters. See the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector:) for NSObject.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `NSObject`'s `performSelector` methods:

```
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)object;
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)object1 withObject:(id)object2;
```